# Javascript - How do I delete the DOM Element by cliking (This command)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to delete a DOM element when I click the button.
I assumed that through 'this' I could achieve that easily.
However, 'this' doesn't work in this case.

I tried as below.

```
deletebutton.addEventListener('click',function()
{this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode)})
```

How do I delete the element when I click the DOM Object?

How the page works is
I click the Add Movie button,
and the code reads through the informatin I input
and generates the cards according to the information I put,

Full code is in the following link.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/mdVWddz

Thank you in advance

Comment: You call `.removeChild()` on the same element you pass it for removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your code for this

```
deletebutton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.parentNode.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
    deletebutton.addEventListener('click',function()
{this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode)})
```

with

```
    deletebutton.addEventListener('click',function()
{this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)})
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest using selectors rather than hardcoding the element. After that, you can specify it inside the listener that you want to remove that selected element.

The HTML code example:

```
<div class="cards">
<div id="card-1">
Your card goes here
</div>
</div>
```

Now as the card is added according to the after the loading of DOM, we will use the concept of Event Delegation to add event listeners. We will all event listener on the parent i.e. cards class, and check if it returns an id.

```
document.querySelector('.cards').addEventListener('click', event => {
if(event.target.id !== ''){
let storeID = event.target.id;
document.getElementById(storeID).remove();
}
}
```

This will remove the element from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can rather make use of the getElement or querySelector functions which will allow you to directly access the DOM element in question.